# Trying to add number of days to Date variable (Angular 13, Typescript), and some months seem return wrong date information

Tags: typescript, angular13

```
addDays(date : Date, days : number) : Date {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
  }
```

this is the method that adds the days. april only has 30 days, when i add say 14 days from april 18th it says April 31 instead of May 1st. anyone else have this issue? strange thing to is it only does this on some months but not others.

Comment: Can you give a reproducable example input to produce your error? The function works fine for me

Comment: As said, it works as well for me.

Comment: If you are creating your date object like this `new Date(2022, 4, 18)` then be aware that the month is 0-based so that date is actully in May

Comment: im working on getting a reproducable example. i am passing the original date object from a firebase timestamp. not sure if that makes a difference or not

Comment: got it working now, forgot that i was adding 1 to the month for displaying and such. thanks everyone for the assistance.